# Do-loop isn't terminating in tic-tac-toe game

Tags: java

the wincondition is in siegBedingung(). I want the do-loop to stop if siegBedingung() is true but even tho it seems like the wincondition is met, the loop doesn't terminate. ausgewählteReihe is the chosenRow and ausgewählteSpalte is the chosenColumn of the player.

My thoughts: If player 1 choses 2,2 and he got already his mark on 1,2 and 3,2 it should verify the second win condition and return true, so the while condition of the do loop is met and it terminates.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TTT {
    static Scanner sc =  new Scanner(System.in);
    static final int spalte = 3;
    static final int reihe = 3;
    static int[][] feld = new int[reihe][spalte];
    static int leer = 0;
    static int kreuz = 1;
    static int kreis = 2;
    static int spieler;
    static int ausgewählteReihe;
    static int ausgewählteSpalte;
    static int spielerSymbol;
    static boolean siegBedingung;

public static void main(String[] args) {


    start();
    do {
    brett();
    zug();
    siegBedingung();
    }while(siegBedingung == false);
    System.out.println("Spieler " + spielerSymbol + " gewinnt.");
}

public static void start() {
    for(int zählerReihe = 0; zählerReihe < reihe; zählerReihe++) {
        for(int zählerSpalte = 0; zählerSpalte < spalte; zählerSpalte++) {
            feld[zählerReihe][zählerSpalte] = leer;
        }
    }
    spielerSymbol = 1;
}

public static void zug() {
    boolean validInput = false;
    do {
        if(spielerSymbol == 1) {
            System.out.println("Spieler 1 (Kreuz) ist am Zug."); 
        }
        if(spielerSymbol == 2) {
            System.out.println("Spieler 2 (Kreis) ist am Zug.");
        }
        System.out.println("Geben Sie die gewünschte Reihe ein.");
        ausgewählteReihe = sc.nextInt() -1;
        System.out.println("Geben Sie die gewünschte Spalte ein.");
        ausgewählteSpalte = sc.nextInt() -1;
        if(ausgewählteReihe >= 0 && ausgewählteReihe < reihe && ausgewählteSpalte >= 0 && ausgewählteSpalte < spalte && feld[ausgewählteReihe][ausgewählteSpalte] == leer) {
            feld[ausgewählteReihe][ausgewählteSpalte] = spielerSymbol;
            validInput=true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Das ausgewählte Feld ist nicht gültig.");
        }
    }while(!validInput==true);
    spielerSymbol = (spielerSymbol == 1) ? 2 : 1;
}

public static boolean siegBedingung() {
    return(feld[ausgewählteReihe][0] == spielerSymbol && feld[ausgewählteReihe][1] == spielerSymbol && feld[ausgewählteReihe][2] == spielerSymbol
    || feld[0][ausgewählteSpalte] == spielerSymbol && feld[1][ausgewählteSpalte] == spielerSymbol && feld[2][ausgewählteSpalte] == spielerSymbol
    || feld[1][1] == spielerSymbol && feld[2][2] == spielerSymbol && feld[0][0] == spielerSymbol
    || feld[0][2] == spielerSymbol && feld[1][1] == spielerSymbol && feld[2][0] == spielerSymbol);
}
public static void brett() {
    for(int zählerReihe = 0; zählerReihe < reihe; zählerReihe++) {
        for(int zählerSpalte = 0; zählerSpalte < spalte; zählerSpalte++) {
            System.out.print("|");
            zelle(feld[zählerReihe][zählerSpalte]);
        }
        System.out.print("|");
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void zelle(int inhalt) {
    switch(inhalt) {
    case 0: System.out.print("_"); break;
    case 1: System.out.print("X"); break;
    case 2: System.out.print("O"); break;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I tested your code and it worked. I needed this things to change:

```
start();
do {
    spielerSymbol = (spielerSymbol == 1) ? 2 : 1;
    brett();
    zug();
} while (!siegBedingung());
System.out.println("Spieler " + spielerSymbol + " gewinnt.");
```

in `zug()` remove the last line

change `siegBedingung` like the othe user suggested:

```
public static boolean siegBedingung() {
    return (feld[ausgewählteReihe][0] == spielerSymbol && feld[ausgewählteReihe][1] == spielerSymbol
            && feld[ausgewählteReihe][2] == spielerSymbol)
            || (feld[0][ausgewählteSpalte] == spielerSymbol && feld[1][ausgewählteSpalte] == spielerSymbol
                    && feld[2][ausgewählteSpalte] == spielerSymbol)
            || (feld[1][1] == spielerSymbol && feld[2][2] == spielerSymbol && feld[0][0] == spielerSymbol)
            || (feld[0][2] == spielerSymbol && feld[1][1] == spielerSymbol && feld[2][0] == spielerSymbol);
}
```

Comment: Hi, added it, but it still doesn't terminate.

Comment: Why is the variable the same name as the method?

Comment: @AndrewLi ask OP, he named it this way

Comment: @JohnnyAW It should be fixed.

Comment: Oops, I dont need the variable actually and deleted it. but `}while(!siegBedingung())` isnt terminating either

Comment: so it returns false

Comment: @Cali if the loop doesn't terminate in this case, your function `siegBedingung()` doesn't work properly, can you describe the win-condition?

Comment: @AndrewLi how is that related to the asked question?

Comment: I believe my answer solves the issue, though i didn't test it

Comment: @JohnnyAW yes of course, in `zug()` the player does an input for the row and column he choses. They are called `ausgewählteReihe` and `ausgewählteSpalte`. then the element of the board array `feld[ausgewählteReihe][ausgewählteSpalte]` is getting the current players mark `spielerSymbol`. the wincondition is in `siegBedingung()` and basically says if all cells in the row of the chosen row, the column of chosen column or the diagonals have the mark of the current player it should return `true`.

Comment: @Portable i have now exactly what you suggested but it didnt help unfortunately

Comment: i checked my solution and it doesn't change anything :(

Comment: what if you remove the last line in `zug()` and put it after `siegBedingung`?

Comment: do you mean  `spielerSymbol = (spielerSymbol == 1) ? 2 : 1;` in `siegBedingung()`? then I get error "unreachable code"

Comment: @JohnnyAW Thank you very much for your effort. It worked. Tho I didnt quite get what exactly was the problem with having that player switch in the zug() function. Still thank you a lot again

Comment: the problem was, you switched the player before checking the win condition, so you checked for the wrong player